# No longer able to add email aliases in Google Apps user's account

Tags: g-suite, gmail

I'm using Google Apps for my domain. I'm the only user in the account. Recently I lost ability to add email aliases in Gmail of admin user. On attempt to add new one I get error "Functionality not enabled."

[image]

I've digged through billion of setting in Admin Panel of Google Apps but didn't find anything that can be related to this.

`Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP server when configuring a "from" address hosted outside your email domains.` is enabled in Google Apps Admin.

What am I missing ?

Comment: now a paid feature ? please call googleapp support/reseller

Comment: Is that official information or your guess ? Could you point me to official link where it says it became paid feature ? The feature works in my regular free @gmail.com account.

Comment: It was a guess, as why I didn't wrote an answer, but my main point behind was to check at google for change, as it was working before. I seen you did check, so iam glad you find the problem. have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that Google services are getting worse every day since Larry took over.

I figured out how to "fix" this issue.

1. Go to your Google Admin Console and then click on "Google Apps"
2. Click "Gmail" Click "User Settings"
3. Scroll down to "SMTP relay service" and click Configure
4. Set configurations to the following:

> Allowed senders: Only registered app users in my domain
>   Authentication: Only accept mail from the specified IP addresses (no). Require SMTP authentication (yes)
>   Encryption: Require TLS encryption (yes)

Once I did these settings I was able to add my additional emails the same as I could in my personal account.

**UPDATE:** Aaaand it's not working. It fails to authenticate with its own SMTP server even though password and username are correct giving me `Authentication failed. Please check your username/password. [Server response: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1` error. Great job, Larry!

**UPDATE2:** And I just got email that explains why it fails to authenticate. Google blocks itself. Genius! :)

> Someone recently used your password to try to sign in to your Google
>   Account xxxx@gmail.com. This person was using an application such as
>   an email client or mobile device.
>
> We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to
>   access your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt:
>
> Friday, May 29, 2:41 PM GMT  IP Address: 2607:f8b0:4001:c03::229
>   (mail-ie0-x229.google.com)  Location: Unknown
>
> If you do not recognize this sign-in attempt, someone else might be
>   trying to access your account. You should sign in to your account and
>   reset your password immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the setting called "Allow per-user outbound gateways", this can be found in the Admin Console under  "Configure advanced settings for Gmail" and then search for "End User Access".

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have simple gmail account and unsuccessfully tried to add there my own mail to use google as SMTP relay. I have succeeded a few moments ago. The final obstacle was mentioned here 'self-blocking' by google. Two tips from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/GyeMcHv1U-g/OsnNHBGUKYgJ) have helped me:

First

> The process gets quite complex and uncertain at this point.  You might need to lower the security settings while doing the set up, but can go back to normal after it is accepted.
>   First, sign into the account that got the message.  Go to settings > Accounts and Import > Other Google account settings > Security > View all events (under Recent Activity).  If you see a blocked access warning, click on Yes this was me (or similar wording).

Second

> 4) It will fail. If it fails with a 534 error, then there is a workaround:
>  leave the window open, open a new one, and unlock your account using https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
>   5) Immediately go back & try again to submit. For me, the 534 error didn't come up the second time...
>   Hope that helps!